# How do I define methods in stateless components?

Tags: reactjs

If I simply have:

```
const App = function() {
    return (
        <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
    )

}
```

How do I define the `renderList` method?

I can't do `const renderList = function() {}` (nor with `var` or `let`). I can't do `renderList() {}`.

What's the right syntax?

Comment: what do you want renderList to do?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Render a list.

Comment: I get that. I mean what kind of list? like whats rendering this component? what are the contents of renderList?

Comment: yeats you are being very negative. it looks like some people tried to answer without understanding exactly what you want to do and syntactically they were off. I want to know what the purpose of this is and why you want do do things like this. because thats the only way to give a full answer. if you dont want to explain then I wont answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114176/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-yeats).

Comment: @JohnRuddell dropping in from 2018, you are so patient to deal with this guy in the chat!

Comment: Fun to come back to in 2019 as React has moved from stateless, pure functions *not* having state or methods etc to it almost being the preferred way to create components:

2016:
"Dont put methods in your function, u idiot! They're supposed to be pure! Its v. simple. Classes for logic / state. Functions for pure, dumb rendering, no state, no lifecycles

2019:
"Hey, use `useState` & `useEffect` to manage lifecycle & state & by all means create methods but u cant access them outside like a class, so think carefully re what actually needs to be in your component & what should live in utils

Comment: @NewbieAid Yea, Honestly I find it a little weird. Syntactially, I could see how someone would find the nuances of `useEffect` (for instance) really confusing (as a newer javascript dev). I feel like this particular movement (feels like a fad really) has been a divergence from the direction of the ES standards. Moving away from ES6 onwards. I prefer classes for most use cases personally. I've seen so many SO questions with massive `App` functions that essentially become unreadable... but its functional!

Answer (score 43):

I am hesitant to give a solution to this because inline `Stateless Functions` are not supposed to have methods. if you want a method you should use a `Class` and theres nothing wrong with using a class. Its all based on what you need to do. `Stateless Functions` are designed to be a super light weight way to render something that doesn't need methods, or a state or even a this context (in terms of a class).

you **should** be doing it like this.

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        // note this is a Stateless Component because its a react class without a state defined.
    }
    renderList = () => {
        return <span>Something Here</span>;
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
    }
}
```

a **HACK** way that **I wouldn't recommend** (but does solve your question in the way you want it to) would be like this.

```
const App = () => {
    let renderList = () => {
        return <span>Something Here</span>
    }
    return <div>{renderList()}</div>
}
```

The reason why its generally a bad practice is because you are creating a function and all the memory allocation needed every render cycle. Subsequently, the internal diffing optimizations that react provides is generally useless if you do this because a new function gives a different signature than the prior render cycle. If this had a lot of children, they would all be forced to re-render!

### Edit - React Version 16.8.0 +

You can use Hooks to do this. I would recommend using `memo` to memoize the function, this way you aren't creating it in memory each render cycle.

```
const RenderList = React.memo(props => (
  <span>Something Here</span>
))
```

Comment: @Yeats, I do provide a stateless function at the end of my answer. I never said a stateless COMPONENT isn't supposed to have methods, my answer has a method on a stateless component.

Comment: I say a stateless function isn't supposed to have a method. `var myStatelessFunction = function(props){}`... is different from... `class myStatelessComponent extends Component`

Comment: No idea where you get "inline" from.

Comment: The docs literally call them stateless functions. from the docs.. says they are `pure functions of their props` and that they `must not retain internal state, do not have backing instances, and do not have the component lifecycle methods.` theres no lifecycle methods. theres no backing instances aka `this.someMethod` its right there in the docs man

Comment: They also call them `classes`.

Comment: Exactly. They say nothing about them not having methods.

Comment: its a function. its not a class. functions dont have methods classes do. its a basic javascript thing. in es5 it would be prototype methods but not the function

Comment: Well, you should talk to the guys over at Facebook then. Maybe you could rewrite the official docs?

Comment: I know a few of them personally... and I've talked about this before. regardless its pointless to describe this any more because you dont understand the concept. You should read up on contexts with functions and classes.

Comment: This isn't a react thing buddy its a vanilla javascript thing. basic javascript. and again with the insults man. gotta cheer up :)

Comment: Stateless components is a vanilla javascript thing?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I applaud your patience

Comment: Hi @JohnRuddell. resurrecting a very old thread - but would you care to please elaborate why you don't recommend the `let renderList = () =>` way? I have a more complex, but functionally similar example, where i need to perform a recursive calculation before returning the element. it would be cleaner to put it into a function rather sticking the whole thing into the `return`, but I don't need to track its state, so using a stateful component feels like overkill. I'm a react n00b, so am very curious as to why you think that isn't a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @ebr I am on the road so I may be brief but yes, the reason why it is a bad idea is because you are creating a function and all the memory allocation needed every render cycle. Subsequently, the internal diffing optimizations that react provides is generally useless if you do this because a new function gives a different signature than the prior render cycle. If you don't need state, then define that function as a standalone (not inside your component function) and pass props.. basically another functional component. That way the function is created once at runtime. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JohnRuddell I also found this thread because I assumed functional components were the go-to choice for stateless components, and wanted to hang a method on my function. I was having difficulty with the syntax, and boy-howdy am I glad I did. Your explanation of the per-render cycle costs was sufficiently cautionary that I will opt for the simpler syntax and more conceptually-consistent class components. FYI, I wrote a fiddle for anyone who wants to see what 'this' is, as John recommended: http://jsfiddle.net/vipatron/b09v57cj/3/

Comment: @JohnRuddell, initially you said `if you want a method you should use a Class and theres nothing wrong with using a class`. Now that we have hooks, is it acceptable and better (in the context of React app) to define methods inside SFC with `memo`? Or should I stick with `Class`?

Comment: @akmalhakimi1991 when i said that hooks wasn't a reality. You can use hooks like useCallback and useMemo, useEffect... Etc to do basically anything a class form component can. One thing to note though. Hooks add time as a factor to your code. The time at which this function was created your props may be different than when someone does something to run a callback for instance. So understanding and properly implementing hooks is a must.

Answer (score 7):

```
const App = function() {
  const renderList = ()=> {
      return "this variables"
     }

    return (
        <div>{renderList()}</div>
    )

}
```

Comment: why do you hate arrow functions?

Comment: This is working in my case.
Please check whether you called like this.renderList().
In this case, you have to call renderList() like above (without this)

Answer (score 2):

You would want to do something like this

```
const App = function() {

    return (
        <div>{renderList()}</div>
    )

}
  function renderList(){
      return "this variables"
     }
```

Naturally this is a bad approach you its recommended that you pass in functions as props and stateless component are always dumb componets. Say if you are using redux for example you can have your component render like this

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
const App = (props) => {
   return (
      <div> {props.renderList} </div>
    )
}
function renderList (){
   return "your render logic"
}
export default connect(null, {renderList})(App)
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either. Same error as the rest of them. "has no method "renderList".

Comment: Check my edited answer. If that doesn't work. You need to paste your full code

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with declaring methods outside. I agree it may be cumbersome since you have to pass required data (instead of const { myProp } = this.props). But at the same time, you make your methods into pure functions

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>{this.renderList()}</div>
  )
}

App.renderList = () => {
    return 'This is my list'
}
```

Comment: `this.constructor.renderList()` is what you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can create render list function as standalone and use function parameter to pass props into function.

Comment: Could you please add some lines of pseudo code at least to help question author