# Why are stateless functions not supposed to have methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read in multiple places that stateless functions in React are not supposed to have inner functions. Why is it so, though it works?

```
const Foo = () => {
 let bar = () => {
    return <span>lorem ipsum</span>
 }
 return <div>{bar()}</div>
}
```

This works. But, why is this not supposed to be done?

Comment: I dont see a method?

Comment: a) that's not a method, that's a local function b) there's no advantage of having the `bar` as an inner function here

Comment: sorry. I thought that was a method. b)In this case, no, but I had a more complicated issue, and i found in a stackoverflow answer that i am not supposed to put `bar` inside `foo`. So, why am I not supposed to do so?

Comment: @JonasW. Since functions are objects in javascript, aren't functions inside functions `methods`?

Comment: Nope. `bar` is not associated to `Foo`

Comment: @JonasW. I am sorry for asking dumb questions, but why is it not associated, and what do you mean associated?

Comment: If you would do `Foo.bar = () => ...;` then `bar` would be a *method* of `Foo` as there is a direct relationship between them. (And there are no dumb questions, just dumb answers, I'm here to help :))

Comment: Methods are similar to Functions in that they both are... functions. However, they differ in that Methods are a property of an object. `bar()` here is *not*  a method because you cannot do `Foo.bar()` and also because `this` doesn't make sense inside `Foo`.

Comment: Could you provide a source that supports what you're saying, so that we can clarify what you are asking? It is possible that you're asking about the difference between a Stateless component (function, which ideally doesn't redeclare inner functions every time it is called) and a Stateful one (class, which needs at least one `render` method) but it could also just be that you're misusing the term "method".

Comment: @JonasW. So can I write the code like above? Is it correct or are there any issues with it? (like you can write `var` inside a `for` loop but you won't generally do it because it is redeclared).

Comment: @TomFenech https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716629/how-do-i-define-methods-in-stateless-components  first answer for this, and in some other place i don't remember where

Comment: No using inner functions is totally fine. Its just not a "method" and therefore your code is not related to your question.

Comment: @JonasW. ummm, i'll modify the question to read inner functions. And is writing the above code fine?

Comment: @illiteratewriter that question is not very useful in my opinion. If you are really talking about inner functions, then you already have your answer.

Comment: @TomFenech I know it is fine to have inner functions, but the question is, is it fine to have inner functions in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.** This answer assumes that the use of the word "method" was incorrect, and that we are actually talking about an inner function, as in the example provided in the question.

A stateless component is defined as a function which returns something that can be rendered by React:

```
const MyStatelessComponent = function (props) {
  // do whatever you want here

  return something; // something must be render-able by React
}
```

To (re-)render the component, React calls the function, so it makes sense to perform expensive computations in advance and save their result outside of the function.

In your toy example, the function `bar` is declared once per render, and only used once. Let's assume that it was *slightly* more complicated and pass it a single parameter:

```
const Foo = () => {
  let bar = text => {
    return <span>{text}</span>
  }
  return <div>{bar("lorem ipsum")}</div>
}
```

By moving `bar` outside of the component, you don't need to create the function once per render, you just call the function that already exists:

```
const bar = text => {
  return <span>{text}</span>
}

const Foo = () => {     
  return <div>{bar("lorem ipsum")}</div>
}
```

Now your component is ever-so-slightly more efficient, since is does less work every time it is called.

Also note that `bar` is almost the same as a stateless component now, and could easily be turned into one by making the function take a `props` object rather than a single string argument.

But the bottom line is that you can do whatever you want inside the stateless component. It just is worth bearing in mind that it will happen once per (re-)render.

Answer (score 0):

While still valid code, as far as react is concerned, the above example is not a stateless component.

A stateless component is basically a shortcut to the `render` method of a stateful component (without the same life-cycle) and should "ideally" only return data, not define methods or actually manipulate or create additional data or functionality. With a stateful component, ideally, you do not define methods within the `render` method so none should be added in a stateless component.

By defining a method, function, or parameter inside of a stateless component but outside of the render method, you are essentially saying that there is a possibility of manipulation within the stateless component, which defeats the purpose.

Mind you, it's still valid code...but just not "react" ideal.

Comment: This is still considered a stateless component. Stateless components don't have to be considered immutable with their prop data, they just simply don't have access to the React lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

The function `Foo` is basically the render method of the React component. Therefore, it will be called everytime the component needs to be rendered. By declaring a local function inside it, it will create a new function everytime the component re-renders, which is bad.
Either declare the function outside or implement a stateful component instead.

Comment: While this is technically correct, it doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: `By declaring a local function inside it, it will create a new function everytime the component re-renders, which is bad. ` not really. It (maybe) creates a new closure, but im not sure why that should be bad...

Comment: It's not necessarily "bad" it's just pointless to create a new function multiple times if it always does exactly the same thing and will only ever be called once.