# React Checkbox Depends on Parent State

Tags: reactjs

In my parent component, I have a regular component that renders checked based off state and it can call a function:

```
<input
    name='shiftOne'
    type='checkbox'
    onChange={() => this.onCheck('shiftOne')}
    checked={this.state.shiftBools['shiftOne']}
/>
```

This works fine except for a warning in the console saying that I am switching from controlling and uncontrolling, but it doesn't break anything.

Trying to do the React way, I seperate this Checkbox out into it's function:

```
function Checkbox (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type='checkbox'
          name={props.name}
          checked={props.checked}
          onChange={() => props.handleCheckChange(props.name)}
        />
        {props.text}
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Checkbox
```

And then I render it in my Root App Component:

```
<Checkbox
    checked={this.state.shiftBools.shiftOne}
    name={'shiftOne'}
    onChange={() => this.handleCheckChange('shiftOne')}
    text={shiftOne[0] + ' ' + shiftTwo[1]}
/>
```

When I use the Checkbox functional component, it's on change doesn't work, it just always stays checked. Also, it doesn't even call the function in the onChange. I tried to console.log inside it and it's not called:

```
 handleCheckChange = () => {
    console.log(1)
    this.setState({
      shiftBools: {
        ...this.state.shiftBools,
        shiftOne: this.state.shiftOne
      }
    })
  }
```

I am trying to think more in React and just using the input in the parent class works fine, I'm just not sure why the functional component isn't working. All the data is in my parent state and whether the checkbox is checked or not depends on the data I have in that state.

*** EDIT ***

I changed the functional component to a Class component:

```
class Checkbox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }

  handler() {
    this.props.onCheck(this.props.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name={this.props.name}
          checked={this.props.checked}
          onChange={this.handler}
        />
        {this.props.text}
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I deal with the parent function through a handler function. I also binded the parent function, as I wasn't before:

```
this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
```

Now my checkbox is rendered in the parent function like so:

```
<Checkbox
  name={"shiftOne"}
  checked={this.state.shiftBools.shiftOne}
  onCheck={this.onCheck}
/>
```

This post helped me: [How do I define methods in stateless components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716629/how-do-i-define-methods-in-stateless-components) 
although my question was a little vague. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you post a minimal, verifiable example in a code sandbox. Just the `<App/>` and a `<Checkbox/>` Hard to see how they fit together and how you're managing state/props with these snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you are calling `onChange` handler

Change

```
onChange={() => props.handleCheckChange(props.name)}
```

To

```
onChange={props.handleCheckChange(props.name)}
```

also, change the way of passing handler down has `props` to **Checkbox component**

```
<Checkbox
    checked={this.state.shiftBools.shiftOne}
    name={'shiftOne'}
    onChange={this.handleCheckChange('shiftOne')}
    text={shiftOne[0] + ' ' + shiftTwo[1]}
/>
```

Comment: If I do it this way, I get props.handleCheckChange is not a function. TypeError.

Comment: You should also change the way you are passing the props into checkbox component, i have edited the answer please check

Comment: I was using a stateless component with a function. Apparently I need to do this with a Class component. From there I need to call my parent function with a handler function in my child. I edited my initial question.