# Why updated props are not reflecting in .then function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling a handleClick function on which call fetchApi action, which  stores response in redux and return a promise to which, I have attached a .then to that in which I should get updated values from redux store, which I am getting outside .then on rerender but not inside .then
you can check this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/what-is-the-reason-z6qt6

```
function App(props) {
  console.log(props.fetchApiRes, "outside handleclick");
  const getProps = () => props;

  function handleClick() {
    props.fetchApi().then(() => {
      console.log(props.fetchApiRes, "inside then");
      console.log(getProps().fetchApiRes, "still not getting ....");
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapDisptach = {
  fetchApi
};
const mapProps = ({ fetchReducer }) => {
  return {
    fetchApiRes: fetchReducer.fetchApi
  };
};
```

Comment: I believe this is intended behaviour. If tracked props are updated, a rerender should occur, which is where you should be using the props. the props object inside the function call are still the stale props object.

Answer (score 1):

What I would first advise is transforming your functional `App` component into class-based one (since this component is not pure functional by its composition).
In that way you would be allowed to have instance methods (like `handleClick`), have access to lifecycle methods, use props via `this`, etc. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719217/7956790

What the next flow would be is to utilize the power of lifecycle methods like `componentDidUpdate` which exposes `prevProps` as the first argument that you can use to compare it with the current `props`, and execute whatever logic you need accordingly. However, be aware of `state` manipulation in this method (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)!